# Return statment not working in Python function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function

I am trying to write a function to create slices in df based on `product_service` and `emotion` columns in my df.

The function runs and creates the slice but does not give the sliced output as a new df even though I've used the return statement. Can someone please help?

Code:

```
def positive_df(df,product_service,emotion):
    product_df = df[df['product_service']==product_service]
    positive = product_df[product_df['emotion']==emotion]
    positive.dropna(inplace=True)
    return positive
```

When I run the function, it creates the slice:

```
positive_df(df,'Google','Positive emotion')

tweet_text  product_service emotion
    4       @sxtxstate great stuff on Fri #SXSW: Marissa M...   Google  Positive emotion
    55      ÛÏ@mention @mention talking about {link} - Go...    Google  Positive emotion
    72      Do it. RT @mention Come party w/ Google tonigh...   Google  Positive emotion
    75      Holla! RT @mention At google party. Best ever!...   Google  Positive emotion
    84      one thing @mention is doing so great is get a ...   Google  Positive emotion ...    ... ... ...
```

But when I try to return the 'positive' df, I get this:

```
<<function __main__.positive(df, product, emotion)>>
```

How do I get the df as the output?

Comment: How do you call it? Is this script named `main.py`? Do you also have a function `def positive(...)`? It seems like you didn't assign the return value from this function to a variable, but you also happen to have a function with the name "positive". Remember that the variables in a function are local to the function and go away when the function returns. You need to get the return value, and it doesn't have to have the same name as in the function.

Comment: This is very likely an issue with how the function is called - probably OP assumes that "positive" in the local function scope creates a variable in the global scope. But without additional information, this question is impossible to answer.